# Can I get the element that addEventListener() was registered to from the callback?

Tags: javascript, dom, dom-events, addeventlistener

When using [EventTarget.addEventListener()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener), is it possible to get the element that the listener was registered to when the callback is called?

I'm aware of the [event.target](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/event.target) property, but that is the element that triggered the event which doesn't have to be the same element as what the listener was registered on.

[Here's an example](http://jsfiddle.net/Z9syB/2/) of what I mean. Consider the following HTML:

```
<p id="1">paragraph <span>1</span></p>
<p id="2">paragraph <span>2</span></p>
```

And the following Javascript:

```
document.getElementById("1").addEventListener("click", myfun);
document.getElementById("2").addEventListener("click", myfun);

function myfun(ev) {
    ev.target.style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
}
```

In this example I want to color the `<p>` that is clicked yellow, but since I'm using event.target, when the 1 or 2 is clicked only that is colored and not the whole paragraph.

Comment: Side note: `id` values starting with digits are fine for how you used them there, but you can't use them in CSS selectors (e.g., `#1` is an invalid selector). For that reason, I'd steer clear of `id`s starting with digits...

Comment: I think you can use a combination of document.elementFromPoint(x, y); and coordinates from ev

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, thanks for the tip I'll keep that in mind for the future, I'm not usually using numeric ids, I just did it for this quick example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Within `myFun`, `this` will be the element on which you hooked the listener. That's a feature of how `addEventListener` works.